# About creating a random ID for nested data in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a simple Android app using Firestore. When a user registered through my app, his data will be stored in Firestore under authentication UID. Now what I want to do is that, when that user inserts some data, that data should be stored under a random key under that particular user's UID.

I tried some video tutorials and on my own too. but nothing worked for me. This is the part of the code I have tried:

```
 public class Apply_leave extends AppCompatActivity {
    AutoCompleteTextView SelectLeave, LeaveType;
    TextInputEditText FromDate, ToDate;
    EditText Reason;
    private DatePickerDialog dataPickerDialog_from;
    private DatePickerDialog dataPickerDialog_to;
    Button BtnSubmit;
    BottomNavigationView BtnBottom;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userID;
    String applyLeave;
    DocumentReference documentReference_two;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apply_leave);

        SelectLeave = findViewById(R.id.txt_select_leave);
        LeaveType = findViewById(R.id.txt_leave_type);
        FromDate = findViewById(R.id.txt_from_user);
        ToDate = findViewById(R.id.txt_to_user);
        Reason = findViewById(R.id.txt_reason_user);
        BtnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        BtnBottom =  findViewById(R.id.btn_bottom_navigation);

        BtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String selectLeave = SelectLeave.getText().toString();
                String leaveType = LeaveType.getText().toString();
                String fromDate = FromDate.getText().toString();
                String toDate = ToDate.getText().toString();
                String reason = Reason.getText().toString();

                userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                documentReference_two = documentReference.collection("ApplyLeave").document(applyLeave);
                Map<String,Object> LeaveData = new HashMap<>();
                LeaveData.put("u_name",selectLeave);
                LeaveData.put("u_email",leaveType);
                LeaveData.put("u_company_id",fromDate);
                LeaveData.put("u_job_name",toDate);
                LeaveData.put("u_mobile_num",toDate);
                LeaveData.put("u_pwd",reason);
            }
        });
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

This is my database structure:

[image: This is my database structure]

So if anyone can help me, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with code type, Finally I found it

```
                DocumentReference documentReference_two = documentReference.collection("ApplyLeave").document();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're created a reference to the documented in the subcollection with:

```
documentReference_two = documentReference.collection("ApplyLeave").document(applyLeave);
```

That `document(applyLeave)` in there means that you are specifying what the ID is of the document you want to access. If you want Firestore to generate a new document, use `add()` instead as shown in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

```
documentReference.collection("ApplyLeave").add(LeaveData);
```

Comment: I will try it.. thank you very much for kind support...@Frank...

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me.. Frank,  what I want really was , create a sub collection with the name of "applyLeave" which was settled as a unique sub collection under the "users" main collection. Already I made users collection. As a example, every user has unique sub collection called "applyLeave" in firestore database. So in this case I want to know from you, How to create sub coolection type which I mentioned before. Thank you.

Comment: In addition for more understanding, in applyLeave sub collection I want to add leave data with some fields which are differ from user to user.

Comment: The `documentReference_two` in my answer is a reference to a new document in the `ApplyLeave` subcollection of the current user. When you first write a document to a collection, the collection is automatically created. Are you saying the document is not written? If so, you might want to add a completion listener as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java_18

Comment: DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("users").document(UserId);
                DocumentReference documentReference_two = documentReference.collection("ApplyLeave").document();

Comment: Aha good find, I now see it in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference. `add()` requires that you pass the data in (so it's a replacement for `document().set(...)`). Good catch, glad you got it working.  I updated my answer to use `add(...)` correctly.